# How to handle a Windows 8 XAML/C# app crash

Tags: c#, xaml, crash, windows-8

I've got a Windows 8 app in the store right now and it's been certified for Windows 8 and Windows RT devices. Also, in my Windows Store dashboard, no crashes are shown. For some reason, though, a commenter who reviewed my app says that it crashes on launch in Windows RT, and I have no way to test that (I don't have a Windows RT device).

To help diagnose the problem, I've decided to create a crash page which would launch if the app crashed the last time it opened. Is there a way to set some variables right before an app crashes? That way I could, say, create a variable "recoverymode" that would launch a page asking for more information the next time the app is launched. Or is there some way to do this for Windows 8 apps that I'm not aware of that will automatically send me crash data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app crashes, you should receive CAB files containing crashes from Windows Store sooner or later. Windows Store also provides other app quality reports. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967782.aspx

Alternatively, you could also use 3rd party crash reporting services like the HockeySDK mentioned above. I have seen vendors like Crittercism http://www.crittercism.com/ and BugSense http://www.bugsense.com/ provide crash reports too as a service, they just announced support for Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8. I think even Telerik provides similar features. There may be more so it's worth checking them out..

Answer (score 1):

Checkout: https://github.com/codenauts/HockeySDK-WindowsPhone

It's for win phone but it might give you some ideas and could be very similar.  Basically right before the crash, unhandled exception possibly, the crash data is serialized to storage.  The app checks for that file on start and if it exists it prompts the user asking if they'd like to send the crash data.